# Configuring shardsWhitelist in Solr 6.6

Tags: solr, sharding

Need help to configure shardsWhitelist in Solr 6.6. I have the below line in Solr.xml

```
<str name="shardsWhitelist">${solr.shardsWhitelist:}</str>
```

And I added the following in solrconfig.xml

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <shardHandler class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
        <int name="socketTimeOut">1000</int>
        <int name="connTimeOut">5000</int>
        <str name="shardsWhitelist">https://<URL1>/solr/core0,<URL2>/solr/core0,<URL3>/solr/core0</str>
     </shardHandler>
```

But, I can’t get the solr to acknowledge the configuration:

HttpShardHandlerFactory shardsWhitelist not configured but required (in lieu of ZkController and ClusterState) when using the 'shards' parameter. set -Dsolr.disable.shardsWhitelist=true to disable shards whitelist checks

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Make sure to not use https/http.

<str name="shardsWhitelist">${solr.shardsWhitelist:<SERVERNAME>:PORT/solr/CORENAME,<SERVERNAME>:PORT/solr/CORENAME}</str>a

Example: <str name="shardsWhitelist">${solr.shardsWhitelist:something.com:8985/solr/core_0,something.com:8985/solr/core2}</str>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to NOT use https/http.

${solr.shardsWhitelist::PORT/solr/CORENAME,:PORT/solr/CORENAME}

Example: ${solr.shardsWhitelist:something.com:8985/solr/core_0,something.com:8985/solr/core2}

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the `shardHandlerFactory` element.
The `shardHandler` element is incorrect.

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <shardHandlerFactory class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
        <int name="socketTimeOut">1000</int>
        <int name="connTimeOut">5000</int>
        <str name="shardsWhitelist"><URL1>/solr/core0,<URL2>/solr/core0,<URL3>/solr/core0</str>
     </shardHandlerFactory>
```