# Apache solr distributes search using shards are not working (shardsWhitelist)

Tags: solr

I have installed latest solr and creates multiple cores called **Unicore** and **SAP** core and as per the SOLR configurations of [solr 8.7 distributed search](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/distributed-requests.html#configuring-the-shardhandlerfactory) we need to add the following code in the respective confgiurations directories *solrconfig.xml* file, below *solrconfig.xml* from **Unicore** conf

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <!-- other params go here -->
  <shardHandlerFactory class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">1000</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">5000</int>
    <str name="shardsWhitelist">localhost:8983/solr/SAP</str>
  </shardHandlerFactory>
</requestHandler>
```

the query i used to collect data from shards:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/UniCore/select?q=text:searchString&wt=json&indent=true&shards=localhost:8983/solr/SAP
```

found below issue:

[image]

I did googled a lot and still not able to find the solution. [refernce stackverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036314/configuring-shardswhitelist-in-solr-6-6)

Comment: Have you reloaded the core and its configuration after changing the xml file? Is the change reflected if you go into Solr's Admin and look at the configuration file there?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes the changes were reflecting in SOLR-Admin, I configured to do below answered method and started working. please confirm do i need to add shardHanldeFactory cores in all cores? what is the best practice for PROD?

Comment: @MatsLindh with below answer i get empty results..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modfify ***solr.xml*** under solr server directory => update this file by adding core names into *shardsWhitelist* in the **solsInstance\Server\solr\solr.xml** and restart solr. This is working for **SOLR-8.7** version.

```
<!-- shardsWhiltlisting SAP core for distributed search -->

<shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:60000}</int>
    <str name="shardsWhitelist">${solr.shardsWhitelist:hostName:8983/solr/SAP}</str> 
  </shardHandlerFactory>
```

*Configure HttpShardHanldeFactory shardsWhiltlist for all the cores needed*

```
<str name="shardsWhitelist">${solr.shardsWhitelist:hostName:port/solr/core1,
hostName:port/solr/core2,.., solr.shardsWhitelist:hostName:port/solr/coren,}</str>
```